# How do I write a union method without affecting the other sets?

Tags: java, set

This is the interface

```
public interface Set{
    public static final int MAX=10;
    public void add(int e);
    public Set union(Set s);
    public void display();
}
```

SetImp

```
public class SetImp implements Set{
    private int[] set;
    private int count;

    public SetImp(){
        set = new int[MAX];
        count = 0;
    }

    public void add(int e){
        if(!contains(e))
            set[count++]=e;
    }

    private boolean contains(int e){
        boolean found=false;
        for(int i=0;i<count;i++){
            if(set[i]==e){
                found=true;
                break;
            }
        }
        return found;
    }

    public void display(){
            for(int i=0;i<count;i++)
                System.out.print(set[i] + " ");
            System.out.println();
    }
```

Where I had most of my problems.
Whenever I try to unite Set s with set, the union takes effect in both s.
I tried making a temp variable but it still doesn't work.

```
    public Set union(Set s){
        for(int i=0; i<count; i++){
            s.add(set[i]);
        }
        return s;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code starts with 2 sets:

Given `set1.union(set2)`, there's set1 and set2 of course.

Given: `Set set3 = set1.union(set2);` there are 3 completely separate sets: set1 and set2 did not change, which means set3 is different.

Therefore, you must have 3 sets. Given that at the start of the `union` method there are only 2... that means you must invoke `new SetImp()` someplace, or this is never going to work out.

I'm sure with that hint you can figure this one out :)

Answer (score 0):

Create a new `SetImp` and add both `Set`s to it.

```
public Set union(Set s){
    final Set res = new SetImp();
    for(int i = 0; i < count; i++){
        res.add(set[i]);
    }
    for(int i = 0; i < s.count; i++){
        res.add(s.set[i]);
    }
    return res;
}
```

Comment: Apparently, s.count and s.set cant be used as symbols.

Comment: Can you change the interface?

Comment: No sadly, I understand that I can use getters. I have a feeling my professor didn't think this problem through. Thanks for helping anyway.